# MMS body missing in Motorola Atrix 2

Tags: android, android-intent

I use following code to send MMS,

```
String message = Fname + Mobileno + Homeno + Workno
                                + Workmail + Homemail + Gtalk + Skype
                                + Address + Company + Title + Website;
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        i.putExtra("address",orgphonenumber);
                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Talk&Share/Images/profpic.png");
                        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
                        i.putExtra("sms_body","Hello");


                        i.setType("image/png");
                        i.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
                        startActivityForResult(i, ONLINE);
```

The above code runs on all devices and shows both image and body text.But on Motorola Atrix 2,it shows blank text in body.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You set the type twice, with different values. Is it correct?

Comment: sorry, that was actually a typo. Problem still exists.Please check..